# Is it possbile to write files with MySQL via SQL injection?

Tags: mysql, security, sql-injection

Long story short, we found files promoting prescription drugs on our server that we didn't put there. The Windows server has very old applications and runs MySQL 5.1.11.

Beyond other security flaws, could SQL injection be used to write files to the server file system? I am certain that some of these old applications are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I would NOT think that this is possible, but I seem to remember reading somewhere that MySQL could access the "command line" and write files via it though I can not locate a source for that info. Then again, my mind could be playing tricks on me.

If this is possible, is there a setting that can disable it?

Also, I'm not looking for the answer that says get rid of the SQL injection vulnerability. While that obviously needs to be done; I'm looking for a quick short term fix that will prevent the rogue files from magically appearing again while the SQL injection vulnerabilities are being fixed. Fixing all the old applications is going to take lots of time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, especially with suitably careless configuration.

For example, there is [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

But it's also more likely to be a different security problem.  I'd seriously consider taking the software offline quickly, especially if the database contains any confidential or private information

Comment: That defiantly qualifies. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

as Colin Pickard shows, yes.

but even if you can't update your application, i doubt it needs the rights it's currently running with. you need to check the user it logs in to mysql with and trip those permissions down to the minimum. specifically in this case, you should remove the FILE privilege if your app does not read/write files stored on the mysql server.

Comment: Is this FILE privilege available in the MySQL administrator? Or do I have to go to the console to revoke it?

Comment: you can do this from mysql administrator, but you have to first go to the tools menu and pick options, and turn on "show global privileges" and "show schema object privileges".

Comment: Thank you. Seems like the FILE privilege was NOT granted to the user. I assume this means that user was not able to execute a select command with "INTO OUTFILE".

Comment: Note: the FILE privilege was NOT granted under the Global privileges. I do not see a FILE privilege under the Schema or Schema Object privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the permissions of the application directory to read-only for the web account might work. This assumes that you're not already creating files in it like logfiles and such.